# Using Microsoft.Build.Tasks in msbuild + xbuild

Tags: msbuild, mono, msbuild-task, xbuild

I have the following custom inline task that works in a windows build environment:

```
<UsingTask
    TaskName="Name"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
        ...
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            ...
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

I want this to work with xbuild also. This won't work obviously as the path is windows specific so I also tried using `AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks"` which also didn't work.

So how should I reference `Microsoft.Build.Tasks` in my custom task in a way that would work for both msbuild and xbuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll"` solved the problem.

Looks like `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` is set to whatever is appropriate depending on the running platform so it will always work. Also I had to use v12.0 specifically, v4.0 didn't work.